# Update a previous Raspbian image to rasp b+?

Tags: raspbian, image, update

I'm sorry if the question has been already asked, I couldn't find it.

I bought a raspberry pi 3 2 years ago, and I still use it with no problem.
I bought a new rasp pi 3 b+ 1 week ago, and I tried to use the same image in my other SD card but I stucked on the rainbow screen.
After some research, I found that the problem lied in the raspbian version. So I tried with a new raspbian and had no problem to run it.

Now I'd like to know if there is a way to update my previous image so it can run on my new rasp?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which "version" of raspbian do you have running now?

Comment: Also: are you using a copy of the current Pi3B image or do you use a fresh image that you downloaded 2 years ago? And did you use Noobs to install the OS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course... [download the latest version of Raspbian from The Organization's website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/), and write it to the SD card with the old image on it. It will run on your new RPi 3B+ as well as your RPi 3.

You will need to decide whether to use the "Lite" or the "Desktop" version (probably Desktop version). If you need help with installation, the [instructions are located here.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md)

Good luck & let us know if you have other questions.